# Noetherian Lemma Contradiction

Tags: combinatorics, noetherian

There is a noetherian version of Higman's Lemma which says

> If $X$ is a noetherian poset, then $X^*$ is noetherian.

Now I was thinking, given $X=\{1\}$ we get $X^*=\{1,11,111,\dots\}$ by the concatenation of $X$. In addition, say $X=\mathbb{N}$; however $\mathbb{N}$ is not noetherian with the usual order $<$. If $X$ noetherian, how is $X^*$ noetherian when it never seems to stabilize?

Answer (score 1):

> Short version: This theorem appears to be a statement about topologies, in which case the topology on $X^*$ is *not* supposed to be the topology [induced](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_topology) by the subword order.

The version of Higman's Lemma I was able to find which mentioned a Nötherian condition was in a topological context, for instance, in Goubault-Lorrecq's [*On Noetherian spaces and verification*](http://www.liafa.univ-paris-diderot.fr/~mgehrke/JGL.pdf).

On slide 38, he mentions this result, along with a note that says we require $X^*$ to be equipped with the **subword topology**: every finite list of open sets $\ell=(U_1,U_2,\dots U_n)$ in $X$ defines an open set: 
$$B_\ell = \{\psi: \text{there exists a subword } \zeta\subseteq\psi \text{ such that }\zeta\in U_1U_2\cdots U_n\}.$$

where the product of open sets in $X$ is the set (in $X^*$) of all concatenations of their elements. The subword topology is then the topology generated by the basis of all $B_\ell$.

Specializing to the case where $X=\{1\}$, there is only one nonempty open set, so if $\ell$ contains $k$ nonempty open sets, then $B_\ell=\{\psi: \text{there exists a subword }\zeta=1^k\}$. Of course, this simply means that $B_\ell$ contains every word in $X^*$ except those with fewer than $k$ ones.

You can see that this topology is much finer than the one induced by the subword order. It does not, for instance, have $\{11,111,1111\}$ as an open set. So if we think of Nötherian by any sort of restricted-structure-of-subobjects condition, it should be much easier than we expected for $X^*$ to have the desired restriction.

---

We can actually show, with our bare hands, that $X^*$ is Nötherian for the case you describe. You may find this useful for understanding the subword topology. I will leave to you the main result (which is not hard to prove, but which you should do yourself if you want to see what's happening):

**Exercise:** When $X=\{1\}$, any union of basis elements for $X^*$ is another basis element; moreover, it is one of the elements which was unioned together.

Going back to the presentation: On slide 13, he defines a Nötherian subspace as one for which every open set is compact.

Specializing again to the set $X=\{1\}$, consider any open set in $X^*$: by the exercise this is a basic open set $B_\ell$. Now consider any open cover of $B_\ell$; by the exercise, this is a basic cover (consists of basic sets), and so again by the exercise, there is a single element $B$ in the cover which covers $B_\ell$ by itself.

Therefore, this cover does have an finite subcover, namely $\{B\}$, and hence $X^*$ is Nötherian.

Comment: Ok. This is a great answer. However, what if we think in the categorical sense? Like how can we think of this theorem of noetherianity in terms of categorical noetherianity like with algebraic geometry and not topological noetherianity?

Comment: @JulianRachman: As your question shows, $X^*$ with the order topology is not categorically Nötherian. Perhaps there is some way to interpret the subword topology categorically, but it is not clear to me that the construction $X\to X^*$ (with $X^*$ having the subword topology) is functorial. if you believe that it is, you need to state and prove something about its action on continuous maps. But the subword topology is so coarse that I wouldn't be surprised if something breaks.

Comment: Nono. I am talking about forgetting topology and thinking solely in terms of categories.

Comment: @JulianRachman: You cannot think "solely in terms of categories". If you want $X^*$ to be a Nötherian object, it must be a Nötherian object in some category. ((I suppose you could ask if $X^*$, interpreted as a category, is a Nötherian category. The answer to this question is yes, but that has nothing to do with $X$: *every* poset, interpreted as a category, is a Nötherian category.))

Comment: I understand that. But can you show me that interpretation?

Comment: Ok and how is X^* noetherian then?

Comment: I think I have overstated my claim dramatically :/ It is true that $X^*$ is always categorically Nötherian if you take the poset structure to be containment as lists, which is the way I usually think of $X^*$. But if you take it to be the subword ordering, then I could believe there are $X$ for which $X^*$ is non-categorically-Nötherian.

Comment: so then if we just preserve wqo from X to X^* then our claim is categorically true?

Comment: ^ ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: If all you want is 'true' then you can just use the order $x\leq y$ iff $x$ is a subword of $y$.

Comment: This is not the subword order. The subword order $\leq^*$ not only permits $x\leq^* y$ when $x$ is a subword of $y$, but also when $x$ is elementwise-$\leq$ than a subword of $y$ (where $\leq$ is the order on $X$).